# Using CRF and setting a maximum bitrate with x264 in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264

I am trying to transcode a video to H.264/MP4. I am using the `crf = 20` option but according to the requirements I also want to limit the maximum bitrate to 3 MBit/s.

I was trying to cheat though it by using `x264opts` like this

```
-x264opts crf=20:vbv-bufsize=14000:vbv-maxrate=3000:keyint=40
```

is that the right way to do this? Can this be done or I am stuck with using a contant bitrate and no CRF?

Answer (score 7):

Use `-maxrate` and `-bufsize` to force the VBV (Video Buffer Verifier) to constrain the output bitrate:

```
ffmpeg -i input.file -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -maxrate 3M -bufsize 6M output.mp4
```

3M = 3 mbit/s, you could also use 3000k (for 3000 kbit/s). Set the buffer size according to how much you expect your client to be able to buffer.

See [this guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more information on using x264 with FFmpeg (although it doesn't mention VBV encoding).

Comment: @mark4o I'm certain it doesn't work. I've tested a low CRF and always get higher bitrates than the `-maxrate`. `-maxrate` is only used when `-bufsize` is set. In that case x264 uses VBV encoding and correctly constraints the bitrate.

Comment: The buffer size of the client is 2MB = 14000 kbits, that's why I chose that value. It seems like that the crf overrides the max bitrate constraint. Moreover is there a relationship between optimal maxbitrate and bufsize if the vbv encoding is used?

Comment: the most optimal is to use CRF mode without any additional constraints.

Comment: `-bufsize` works perfectly , I use  `-maxrate 300k` with  `-bufsize 1M` I got smaller file size now.

Answer (score 1):

Just a fair warning for others reading this; I've noticed that VBV (ffmpeg -maxrate for x264) is *far* more indiscriminate about what bits it throws away, than a proper 2-pass rate-controlled encode. A much better (but also, trickier, and more expensive) approach is to encode the entire video using CRF, and then re-encode the offending peaking segments using 2-pass with bitrate-target.

OR, use a newer codec with better encoder-support for capped CRF (I.E. AV1)

Comment: Any suggestion on how to go about doing that 2 pass controlled encode?